# Query for records with overlapping dates in cassandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

Given a table with startDate and endDate columns how do I query for records where the periods overlap. The dates currently use DateField type. Would changing the type to DateRangeField help with this query? We are using Cassandra with Solr.

Answer (score 0):

i am just sharing a data model for records where the periods overlap event

```
CREATE TABLE event (      
start_date date,
id timeuuid,
end_date date,
PRIMARY KEY ((start_date), id))

SELECT * FROM event WHERE start_date =date;
```

i think if you create your data model like this and query like this your problem will be solve.